# Is it possible to configure SAMBA share between ubuntu instance and windows, and if yes how?

Tags: networking, ssh, samba, file-sharing, aws

I have ubuntu 20.04 instance on my AWS Lightsail, is it possible to somehow configure samba share? I need to see shared folders on windows (from my PC that is in different network) from ubuntu instance (is it possible via SSH?). How to solve this problem?

Comment: Reading your question I'd say no problem. Reading your description, I'd say not so easy. You should change the question to "Ubuntu AWS instance" or "Ubuntu Cloud instance".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done. It will require a lot of maintenance, though, as it is not recommended that you have a Samba share open to the entire Internet. A decent level of access restriction can be enforced with the firewall rules that Amazon has, but any time your IP address changes, the Samba share will become unavailable. This can be resolved programmatically, of course, by configuring something on your local computer to edit the network access rules for the Samba share through Amazon's API, but it quickly becomes a house of cards unless you really enjoy working with networks and APIs.

A simpler solution would be to set up [a NextCloud installation](https://nextcloud.com/install/). You can then use the various tools available to set up [synchronised directories](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/latest/user_manual/en/files/desktop_mobile_sync.html), remote directories [via WebDAV](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/latest/user_manual/en/files/access_webdav.html), and the like.

One word of advice, though: if you go down this route, be prepared to update the system every week or two, as the older versions are quickly deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `samba` consider mounting the folder(s) from the cloud instance using `sshfs`. This allows you to access the folder as if it were on your pc.

- ssh is secure
- easy to set up (at least on a Linux client)

I have only done this on Linux clients, but it seems that Windows supports it.  This looks like a good tutorial.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sshfs-to-mount-remote-file-systems-over-ssh